# Про TextField и возможности которые он предоставляют

Tags: swift

Я пытаюсь повторить приложение от Сяоми - конвертер валют. Там имеется 3 поля для ввода. В зависимости от того, какое поле выделено основным при вводе результата, будут меняться данные. Возник вопрос - реально ли такое повторить в Xcode? А то я дизайн приложения повторил, а саму конвертацию настроить не могу.

Еще раз, как должно работать: 3 TextField. При выборе одного из TF и вводе данных в него, другие ТF показывают необходимые данные - цена валюты

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем виде это может быть что-то подобное, здесь через сториборд привязаны события получения и потери фокуса полей, а также событие изменения значений полей при вводе с клавиатуры, в данном варианте печатаемое значение из активного поля просто копируется в два других поля, вы можете сделать конвертацию значений в методах.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField!
    
    private var activeTextField: UITextField?
    
    
    // MARK: --
    
    func updateTextField1(value: String?) {
        
        guard let activeTextField = activeTextField else { return }
        
        if activeTextField == textField2 {
            // TODO: process value
        } else { // textField3
            // TODO: process value
        }
        
        textField1.text = value
    }
    
    func updateTextField2(value: String?) {
        guard let activeTextField = activeTextField else { return }
        
        if activeTextField == textField1 {
            // TODO: process value
        } else { // textField3
            // TODO: process value
        }
        
        textField2.text = value
    }
    
    func updateTextField3(value: String?) {
        guard let activeTextField = activeTextField else { return }
        
        if activeTextField == textField1 {
            // TODO: process value
        } else { // textField2
            // TODO: process value
        }
        
        textField3.text = value
    }
    
    // MARK: UI Events
    
    @IBAction func textFieldEditingDidBegin(_ sender: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = sender
    }
    
    @IBAction func textFieldEditingDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = nil
    }
    
    @IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        switch sender {
            
        case textField1:
            updateTextField2(value: sender.text)
            updateTextField3(value: sender.text)
            
        case textField2:
            updateTextField1(value: sender.text)
            updateTextField3(value: sender.text)
            
        case textField3:
            updateTextField1(value: sender.text)
            updateTextField2(value: sender.text)
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```